# Express doesn't load page only return json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, router

The problem appears when after reloading a page, server return only json instead that page

I'm using React and return static files from build folder, there is also express handles routing, it is reproduced only in production mode when running localhost everything ok

```
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use(['/dota2', '/csgo', '/lol'], generalRoutes);

if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log('Production is running');
  app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

There are routes

```
const router = Router();

router.get('/live', liveMatches);
router.get('/upcoming', upcomingMatches);
router.get('/past', pastMatches);
router.get('/:matchId', getMatchById);
router.get('/opponents/:tournamentId', opponents);
router.post('/past-team-matches', pastTeamMatches);
```

You can visit [mySite](https://esportslife.herokuapp.com/dota2/566624) and you will see json as result but if you clear **matchId** in URL and click on any match the page will load as normal

There is also react-router

```
<ServiceRoute
            key={key}
            path={['/dota2', '/csgo', '/lol']}
            exact
            access
            component={Matches}
          />
          <ServiceRoute
            key={key}
            path={['/dota2/:matchId', '/csgo/:matchId', '/lol/:matchId']}
            exact
            access
            component={MatchInfo}
          />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's follow the route matching that express does in this case:

1. When looking for `/dota2/566624`, it will match here: `app.use(['/dota2', '/csgo', '/lol'], generalRoutes);` and return the JSON.
2. When looking for `/dota2`, it won't match `app.use(['/dota2', '/csgo', '/lol'], generalRoutes);` so it will continue down until it matches `app.get('*', (req, res) => {`, serving the React page.

The problem I see here, is that you're using the very same routes for the API and the front-end routing on React. Ideally, when serving the API and the front-end application from the same server you should prefix the API routes, that way they won't clash with the front-end routes. Let's say that you prefix the API routes with: `/api`. Now you we have:

```
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);
app.use(['/api/dota2', '/api/csgo', '/api/lol'], generalRoutes);

// ... everything is the same down here
```

1. `/api/dota2/566624`. Will match against the endpoint that returns the JSON on the first load.
2. `/dota2/566624`. Will not match the JSON endpoint and will follow down to the `'*'` route that loads the React app, later, once the app is loaded that route will be handled by the router you're using on the react application.

Don't add the prefix as I did in the example above, use the `const router = Router();` you've been using for this purpose as well. I hard-coded the prefix so that I can keep the example short.

One last question is: **Why is this not happening on development?**
I don't have all the information but for what I can see you're serving the front-end application from a different server than the one running the API; in that case you won't have the route clashing, since they are server from different ports, e.g front-end served on `localhost:8080` and API served on `localhost:5000`.

I hope this helps! please comment if you need info!

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my issue,  I use "proxy": "http://localhost:6000" - here it is running my server, from react-app which running on port:3000 locally, I've added 'api/' as you wrote and now I can't get response at all, maybe you need more info please give me know

Comment: Sorry for the delay... well that’s interesting ... I never used the proxy option on the CRA configuration, but it forwards any request that doesn’t accept text/html... take a look at the docs https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/. This means that if you’re making the request via a axios for instance, make sure the request only set te Accept header to application/json

Comment: Thank you sir, the problem really was because of the same routing on front-end as on beck-end, after adding prefix /api it has fixed